# HashMapStore. Print Method not showing correct output

Tags: java, hashmap

I have looked online and i havent been able to fix a problem that i am having.  I am making an employee store using a hashMap but im not sure whether i am supposed to print the toString() or the theEntry.getKey() as i have in my current version.  When using the getKey() method i am getting the wrong output which is:

**Employee's in the Company.****
Employee Name:  James O' Carroll
Employee Id:    James O' Carroll
E-mail:  James O' Carroll

As you can see in the MainApp i want Store.add(new Employee ("James O' Carroll", 18,"hotmail.com")); to be the output.

I will paste my code:

```
//MainApp.
public class MainApp
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new MainApp().start();

    }
    public void start()
    {
        EmployeeStore Store = new EmployeeStore();
        Store.add(new Employee ("James O' Carroll", 18,"hotmail.com"));
        Store.print();

    }

}

//Employee
//Imports:

//********************************************************************
//Employee Class.
public class Employee
{
//Variables.
    private String employeeName;
    private int employeeId;
    private String employeeEmail;
//********************************************************************  
//Constructor.
    public Employee(String employeeName, int employeeId, String employeeEmail) 
    {
        this.employeeName = employeeName;
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
        this.employeeEmail = employeeEmail;
    }
//********************************************************************
//Getters.
    public String getEmployeeEmail() {
        return employeeEmail;
    }
    public void setEmployeeEmail(String employeeEmail) {
        this.employeeEmail = employeeEmail;
    }
    public String getEmployeeName() {
        return employeeName;
    }
    public int getEmployeeId() {
        return employeeId;
    }
//********************************************************************
//toString method.
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [employeeName=" + employeeName + ", employeeId="
                + employeeId + ", employeeEmail=" + employeeEmail + "]";
    }
//********************************************************************





}

//EmployeeStore.
//Imports.
import java.util.HashMap;
//********************************************************************
import java.util.Map;

public class EmployeeStore 
{
    HashMap<String, Employee> map;

//Constructor.  
    public EmployeeStore()
    {
        map = new HashMap<String,Employee>();
    }
//********************************************************************
//Hashmap Methods.
//Add to the Hashmap : Employee.
    public void add(Employee obj)
    {

        map.put(obj.getEmployeeName(), obj);
    }
//********************************************************************
//Remove from the Hashmap : Employee.
    public void remove(String key)
    {
      //Remove the Employee by name.
        map.remove(key);
    }
//********************************************************************
//Print the Hashmap : Employee. 
    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println("\n********Employee's in the Company.********");
        for(Map.Entry<String, Employee> theEntry : map.entrySet())
        {
            System.out.println("Employee Name:\t" + theEntry.getKey());
            System.out.println("Employee Id:\t" + theEntry.getKey());
            System.out.println("E-mail:\t "+ theEntry.getKey());

        }
    }


//********************************************************************  
//********************************************************************


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is clearly wrong:

```
for(Map.Entry<String, Employee> theEntry : map.entrySet())
{
    System.out.println("Employee Name:\t" + theEntry.getKey());
    System.out.println("Employee Id:\t" + theEntry.getKey());
    System.out.println("E-mail:\t "+ theEntry.getKey());
}
```

You're printing the same value three times - how could it be the name, ID *and* email address? You're printing the *key* from the entry, which is always the name. You want the *value* of the entry.

You want this:

```
// This assumes you've renamed all the properties in Employee to be more
// sensible - there's no point in including the "employee" part - we already
// know we're calling a method on Employee
for (Employee employee : map.values())
{
    System.out.println("Employee Name:\t" + employee.getName());
    System.out.println("Employee Id:\t" + employee.getId());
    System.out.println("E-mail:\t "+ employee.getEmail());
}
```

(Or just print `employee` of course. It depends on what you want the output to be.)

Comment: Yeah that worked thank you.  I got that code from some notes and it worked by using this:System.out.println("\n----- FLIGHTS IN THE AIR ----");
  for(Map.Entry<String, Plane>theEntry : map.entrySet())
  {
   System.out.println("Flight Time: \t" + theEntry.getKey());
   System.out.println("Details: \t" + theEntry.getValue());
  }
 } Hoe does that work.

Comment: @SoboLAN: Oh it's a rare day that I don't get *any* downvotes. Sometimes deserved, sometimes not even explained...

Comment: @ConorPendlebury: Well that's printing the key and then the value from each entry... what don't you understand about it?

Comment: It's my first time using it so i dont really understand it :S

Comment: @ConorPendlebury: Your first time using what though? Take each little bit at a time - make sure you understand *each individual line* and don't move on until you have. That way you won't get overwhelmed, with any luck.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to iterate over the values of the map. By doing such, you'll get `Employee` instances in return and can simply define your `print()` method as follows,

```
public void print(){
    for(Employee e : map.values()){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Note that you do not need to explicitly invoke `toString()` because `println` will automatically do that for you.